# what does a three-up mean in below contents?

Tags: meaning

Print proofing **with a three-up**: The two sides show the lightest and darkest prints that are within tolerance. The one in the middle is juust right.

I can guess what it means by reading the whole content, but I don't know why it can be expressed in this way, is it a kind of fixed usage?

Answer (score 1):

In printing, *two-up*, *four-up* etc mean "two (four) pages printed at one time" (nowadays, usually reduced to fit on one page).  I've never met *three-up*, but the meaning is clear.

The OED doesn't appear to list this meaning of *-up*, but it does list *two-up*, one of whose meanings is given as "Two at a time, two together", with a citation relevant to this question, from 1967: "Master output for photo-litho reproduction ‘two-up’"